# what exceptions can "try catch(...)" catch in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, try-catch

The code

```
    try{
        memcpy(p, buf, l);
    }
    catch (...){
        ofstream f("memcpy.error");
        f << "memcpy.error";
    }
```

if p is null,memcpy will throw exception,but catch(...)can't catch it.So,in c++,what do try catch(...) actually do?

Comment: `memcpy` does not throw exceptions.

Comment: Are you talking about Access Violations? And possibly structured exception handling on Visual Studio? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx

Comment: Yes,because if p is null,vs will show First-chance exception at 0x5 (msvcr120d.dll) in.exe: 0xC Access violation writing location 0x0.

Comment: @YuanWen  That is **not** a C++ exception that is a Structured Exception.  Please note the differences.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782915/what-should-i-know-about-structured-exceptions-seh-in-c

Comment: I added Visual Studio to the tags because I believe the question is really about a Microsoft Visual Studio extension. I guess I could have used Visual-c++ instead.

Comment: You mean catch(...) can only handle c++ exception,but not other type exceptions?@PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I handle an access violation in Visual Studio C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610879/how-can-i-handle-an-access-violation-in-visual-studio-c)

Comment: @YuanWen  Ever hear of `throw`?  That is what Microsoft does in their C++ runtime when a Structured Exception occurs.  An access violation SE knows nothing about C++.  It is the Visual Studio C++ runtime that is designed to detect the Access violation and then call `throw`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re

> **”** what exceptions can “try catch(...)” catch in c++?

It can catch any exception produced by a C++ `throw`.

Note by the way that the ellipsis `...` needs to be three periods, not the Unicode `…` ellipsis character, otherwise the compiler will choke on it!

---

Re the code

```
buf = nullptr;
try{
    memcpy(p, buf, l);
}
catch (...){
    ofstream f("memcpy.error");
    f << "memcpy.error";
}
```

The call of [`memcpy` here has formal **undefined behavior**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).

However, a particular C++ implementation can define any behavior, including that which is formally UB, and your compiler Visual C++ may do that, possible with special options. However, [Microsoft's documentation of `memcpy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswaw1wk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does not mention such more well-defined behavior.

On the third hand, undefined behavior includes that you might get some behavior that you erroneously expected, such as the execution going into the `catch` clause.

---

In the 1990's, Microsoft's Visual C++ would catch Windows SEH exceptions (a lower level kind of exception) in `catch(...)`, by default. For example, you can get an SEH exception by dereferencing a nullpointer, which might happen in your `memcpy` call. Happily the compiler no longer has catching of such exceptions as default, but you can specify that behavior by using the [`_set_se_translator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 3):

Answering in the context of the question being tagged as [visual-studio] and [winapi] by implication.

`try/catch` blocks catch `C++` exceptions, while `memcpy` with a NULL destination throws a *Win32 structured exception*.

You can catch those exceptions with `__try/__except` blocks ([Structured Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx)).

Alternatively, you can convert them to C++ exceptions catchable in C++ `try/catch` blocks via [_set_se_translator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> If `p` is null, `memcpy` will throw an exception.

Incorrect. If either pointer is null, it is undefined behavior. Since undefined is "undefined", there isn't much you can do about it when it happens (in a non-implementation dependent way).

Comment: But in vs,it seems that the vs will always throw exception.

Comment: What it throws is not a c++ exception.

Comment: @YuanWen Undefined behavior means that is allowed to happen. If you want to ask about a particular implementation's behavior, you should edit your question to clarify.