# Can an .Net exception be raised from unmanaged code using a delegate function?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, mono, unmanaged

I searched around SO and found various related questions, some answered with essentially "don't do that."

I want to call some unmanaged C++ code that accesses various existing C++ code.  The existing code may have a variety of error conditions that I want to map into C# exceptions.  From doing something similar in Java and JNI, it seemed that it might be possible to have a delegate function to raise defined exceptions, which could then be called directly from unmanaged code.  The calls then look like (csharp)->(unmanaged)->(csharp delegate,throw/set pending exception) and then return back up.

The code below seems to work fine (vs2010, mono).  My question is is there any problem with this approach - e.g. the spec says that the exception is not guaranteed to still be "pending" after unmanaged code is called, or threading issues, etc...

```
// unmanaged.cpp 
#include <cstdio>
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define STDCALL __stdcall

typedef void (STDCALL* raiseExcpFn_t)(const char *);
extern "C" {
  // STRUCT ADDED TO TEST CLEANUP
  struct Allocated {
     int x;
     Allocated(int a): x(a) {}
     ~Allocated() {
    printf("--- Deleted allocated stack '%d' ---\n", x);
    fflush(stdout);
    }
  };

  static raiseExcpFn_t exceptionRaiser = 0;
  EXPORT void STDCALL registerRaiseExcpFn(raiseExcpFn_t fun) {
      exceptionRaiser = fun;
  }
  EXPORT void STDCALL hello(const char * x) {
    Allocated a0(0); 
    try {
      Allocated a1(1);
      printf("1 --- '%s' ---\n", x); fflush(stdout);
      (*exceptionRaiser)("Something bad happened!");
      printf("2 --- '%s' ---\n", x); fflush(stdout);
    } catch (...) {
      printf("3 --- '%s' ---\n", x); fflush(stdout);
      throw;
    }
    printf("4 --- '%s' ---\n", x); fflush(stdout);
  }
}

// Program.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program {
  [DllImport("unmanaged.dll")]
  public static extern void registerRaiseExcpFn(RaiseException method);

  [DllImport("unmanaged.dll")]
  public static extern void hello([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string m);
  public delegate void RaiseException(string s);
  public static RaiseException excpfnDelegate = 
    new RaiseException(RaiseExceptionMessage);

  // Static constructor (initializer)
  static Program() { 
    registerRaiseExcpFn(excpfnDelegate);
  }

  static void RaiseExceptionMessage(String msg) {
    throw new ApplicationException(msg);
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    try {   
      hello("Hello World!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.GetType() + ":" + e.Message);
    } 
  }
}
```

Updated: Corrected test and output, showing mono and Windows (with /EHsc) leaks

```
// Observed output // with Release builds /EHa, VS2010, .Net 3.5 target
//cstest.exe
// --- Deleted allocated stack '0' ---
// --- Deleted allocated stack '1' ---
// 1 --- 'Hello World!' ---
// 3 --- 'Hello World!' ---
// Exception: System.ApplicationException:Something bad happened!

// Observed LEAKING output // with Release builds /EHsc, VS2010, .Net 3.5 target
// cstest.exe
// 1 --- 'Hello World!' ---
// Exception: System.ApplicationException:Something bad happened!

// LEAKING output DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` mono program.exe 
// 1 --- 'Hello World!' ---
// Exception: System.ApplicationException:Something bad happened!
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is really asking for a code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. This isn't asking for a code review, except as an additional comment. Remove the code from the question, and change "The code below seems to work fine" to "That approach seems to work fine", and you still have a complete question. Including the code merely makes it easier to understand what's being asked.

Comment: I added to the code to test resource cleanup in the unmanaged code, and show at the bottom the observed results wih /EHa, /EHsc and under mono on osx

Comment: The output values displayed above were Debug builds under visual studio.  When changed to Release with optimization, /EHsc did fail to run destructors as described by @Hans Passant

Comment: Two useful references talking about some of the issues are   http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime:Documentation:ExceptionHandling and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1deeycx5.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can make this work as long as you run the code on Windows.  Both C++ exceptions and .NET exceptions are built on top of the native SEH support provided by Windows.  You will not have such guarantee on Linux or Apple operating systems however, a concern when you use Mono.

It is important that you build your C++ code with the correct settings, the MSVC++ compiler uses an optimization to avoid registering exception filters when it can see that code can never throw a C++ exception.  That cannot work in your case, your RaiseException delegate target is going to throw one and the compiler has no chance at guessing at that.  You *must* compile with /EHa to ensure your C++ destructors will be called when the stack is unwound.  You'll find more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049836/17034).

Comment: Your detailed discussion (linked) was very useful.  But I am confused.  I updated the test (above) to do some stack allocations, and they seem to be destroyed with /EHa, EHsc AND using mono.  I also tried a custom exception (not shown) and verified that the C# exception is appropriately destroyed.

Comment: As I said, as long as you run this on Windows then you'll be fine.  Using /EHsc is no guarantee you'll have a problem, particularly not in your test code when the C++ compiler can actually see that you are throwing.

Comment: I may answer myself when I can define the situations where things work properly.  For now, it seems that using /EHa does work.

Answer (score 3):

If you're ever planning on running on Mono, the answer is simple:

**Don't do it**

No more code will be executed in the native methods the exception would unwind over. No cleanup, no C++ destructors, nothing.

On the other hand this means that if you're sure none of the native frames on the stack have any cleanup to do (if you're writing C++ code this can be harder than it looks), then you're free to throw managed exceptions at will.

The reason I so adamantly advice against doing this is because I once spent two days tracking down a memory leak because of exception handling unwinding though native frames. It is quite hard to track down and I was quite boggled for a while (breakpoints aren't hit, printfs don't print... but [with the right tools](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/951e11a011) it could have taken 5 minutes).

If you're still decided on throwing managed exceptions from native code, I'd do it just before returning to managed code:

```
void native_function_called_by_managed_code ()
{
    bool result;

    /* your code */

    if (!result)
        throw_managed_exception ();
}
```

And I would limit myself to C in those methods, since it's too easy to get into automatic memory management in C++ that would still leak:

```
void native_function_called_by_managed_code ()
{
    bool result;
    MyCustomObject obj;

    /* your code */

    if (!result)
        throw_managed_exception ();
}
```

This could leak because MyCustomObject's destructor isn't called.

Comment: I updated the code with some resource allocations.  It seems like objects on the stack are cleaned up fine.  Googling seems to agree with your premise on Windows, that destructors will not be called unless using /EHa, but I did not observe that.  And mono seemed to work fine, too.

Comment: @Marvin, I believe your test case is incorrect. If you declare the stack variables as `Allocated a0(0);` and `Allocated a1(1);`, they're not freed. Also note that in your output the objects are freed before the exception is thrown, not after.

Comment: sorry, I should have paid more attention to what you wrote.  You are correct, and the behavior for mono is as you describe.  Interestingly, in the discussions of the future for mono exception handling, there is a mention that it could be simpler and better to use the JNI approach to simply set a pending exception and handle it upon return to managed code.

Comment: The issue [still](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35017) hasn't a clear solution also with modern .NET. In the end a custom [marshaller](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35017#issuecomment-1928635819) for the unmanaged `[LibraryImport]` call could be introduced so it would be completely up to the user to: 1) Store the exception that is supposed to be thrown in the delegate function and 2) Check there was an exception after the return from unmanaged code and throw it. @RolfBjarneKvinge did you talk about a timeframe for this addition?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem with native resources not being freed correctly.

When an exception is thrown the stack gets unwind until it finds a matching try-catch block.

This is all good and nice, but there are some side effects of being in the middle of native and managed.

In regular C# all the objects created in the blocks on the way to the exception would eventually be freed by the garbage collector. But Dispose() isn't called unless you're in a using block.

On the other hand, in C++ if you'd have a native exception, all object created with new() would probably stay dangling and you'll have a memory leak, and the objects on the stack would be destroyed properly when the stack got unwound.

BUT if you don't have /EHa set, and you have a managed exception, it will only unwind the managed code. So, the native destructors of native objects created on the stack might not be called, and you might have memory leaks, or even worse - locks not being unlocked...

Comment: .Net exceptions are implemented using [SEH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and so I believe that native resources would be freed correctly as long as the unmanaged code dealt with exceptions correctly.