# How can I catch a memory exception?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, seh

I'm having an issue catching an exception , this is the error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x01034BB1 in Hello.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x02343DA2.

This is my code:

```
bool VerifyAddress(HANDLE hwnd, DWORD dwAddress, char* bMask, char *szMask )
{
    PBYTE *pTemp = { 0 };

    for ( int i = 0; *szMask; ++szMask, ++bMask, ++i )
    {

        try {
            if ( !ReadProcessMemory( hwnd, reinterpret_cast<LPCVOID>(dwAddress + i), &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), 0 ) ){
                failedRPM++;
                return false;
            }
        } catch(...) {
            failedRPM++;
            return false;
        }

        if ( *szMask == 'x' && reinterpret_cast<char*>(pTemp) != reinterpret_cast<char*>(*bMask)){
            failedMask++;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

DWORD FindPattern(HANDLE hwnd, char* bMask, char *szMask )
{
    for ( DWORD dwCurrentAddress = 0x015A1DB4; dwCurrentAddress < 0x7FFFFFF; dwCurrentAddress++ ){
        if ( VerifyAddress( hwnd, dwCurrentAddress, bMask, szMask )) {
            return dwCurrentAddress;
        }
    }
    return 0x0;
}
```

I have just a question: why the catch is not catching?

Comment: Because that's not really resulting in an exception.

Comment: Because C++ exceptions do not trap hard faults.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  Access violations are structured exceptions (not C++ exceptions), with Microsoft Visual Studio you need to turn on structured exception handling. See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx

Comment: I've never used `ReadProcessMemory` but from the looks of it... do you have access to `reinterpret_cast<LPCVOID>(dwAddress + i)` for `sizeof(pTemp)`? Also, is `hwnd` a valid process handle?

Comment: I would try the `/EHa` as the exception handling model. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx for more details.

Comment: I think it's a mistake to map structured exceptions to C++ exceptions; the semantics are fundamentally different.. In this MS-specific code you can use the MS-specific syntax to handle the structured exception appropriately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++, \_\_try and  try/catch/finally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049502/c-try-and-try-catch-finally)

Comment: `pTemp` is probably on the stack and has trashed the stack, and that's why it's not catching. The name suggests that it is already a pointer, so you shouldn't be using the `&pTemp` but just `pTemp`. Can  you show the code where `pTemp` is declared and initialized too?

Comment: Ah, that means that that I do not have read access to that address ? @RyanP

Comment: Literally answering your question, why your `catch(...)` clause doesn't catch SEH exceptions: You are using Visual Studio 2005 or above. Switching to Visual Studio 2003 is one solution. Fixing the bug is another solution. There seems to be a consensus that the former solution isn't, while the latter is.

Comment: Thank you, sorry. I updated the code, could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a C++ exception that you can catch, it's accessing invalid memory. There's no guarantee that the process is in a sane state for catching anything.

In your particular case, something's probably wrong with `pTemp`, maybe it's a constant. Show us the code.

Comment: pTemp is probably on the stack and has trashed the stack, and that's why it's not catching...

Comment: I edited my coded , now it's complete, thank you for your helping. Can you now help me?

Comment: I'd need to see how FindPattern is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch [SEH exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657.aspx) using a [try-except Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zazxh1a9.aspx). The `__try` and `__except` keywords are specific to Microsoft's compilers.

There are a few considerations, though:

- You cannot mix C++ and SEH exception handling. The result would be undefined.
- Improperly handling SEH exceptions can jeopardize process integrity.
- SEH exception handlers should only be used in very rare cases. In your specific case it will probably hide a bug lingering elsewhere.

With that out of the way, you should probably analyze the issue, and fix the bug. You can use [Application Verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695.aspx) to easily catch memory corruption bugs. You can also set up Visual Studio's debugger to break, when an SEH exception is raised (*Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Exception Settings*: *Win32 Exceptions*).

Comment: Nice detailedanswer. Anyway, I edited my coded, now it's complete, thank you for your helping. Can you now help me?