# Signal Handling on Windows and Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, signals, signal-handling

I have implemented signal handling in C on windows visual studio
spefically for SIGBREAK and SIGSEVG

but when i gave the added the code which could cause segmentation fault, my signal handler function dosent get call

but if used raise(SIGSEVG), signal handler does get called

this is how I am initializing signal
signal(SIGBREAK, signal_handler)
signal(SIGSEVG, signal_handler)

upon further checking I got to know that every time my signal() function is returning NULL
the issue is same on linux platform also(CentOS 7)

so what should I do to fix this

Comment: Windows: does not implement asynchronous signals. Linux: [avoid signal, use sigaction instead](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions in one, probably try focusing a bit. I don't think you can handle a bad memory access in windows, the other one would deserve a closer look. And your code probably has a different problem on Linux. And this is unlikely to produce portable code, you may have to `#ifdef` a bit.

Comment: I tried this, but my signal.h dosen't have implementation of sigaction..

Comment: It does on Linux unless you're compiling in a strict "standard C features only" mode.

Comment: @teapot418 sir if possible can you please share any official documentation which states "you can't handle a bad memory access in windows, "

Comment: At least not in a portable way. This answer points to structured exceptions, I have no experience with those: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32531038/21105992