# SEH on Windows, call stack traceback is gone

Tags: windows, debugging, seh

I am reading this [article](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx) about the SEH on Windows.
and here is the source code of [myseh.cpp](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/viewchm.php/hs/Win32SEH.chm/fig03.htm)

I debugged myseh.cpp. I set 2 breakpoints at `printf("Hello from an exception handler\n");` at line:24  and `DWORD handler = (DWORD)_except_handler;` at line: 36 respectively.

Then I ran it and it broke at line:36. I saw the stack trace as follows.

[image]
As going, **AccessViolationException**  occurred because of `mov [eax], 1`
Then it broke at line:24. I saw the stack trace as follows.
[image]

The same thread but the **frame** of `main` was gone! Instead of `_except_handle`. And ESP jumped from `0018f6c8` to `0018ef34`;it's a big gap between `0018f6c8` and `0018ef34`
After Exception handled.

I know that `_except_handle` must be run at user mode rather than kernel mode.
After `_except_handle` returned, the thread turned to ring0 and then windows kernel modified CONTEXT `EAX` to `&scratch` & and then returned to ring3 . Thus thread ran continually.

I am curious about the mechanism of windows dealing with exception:
WHY the **frame** calling `main` was gone?

WHY the ESP jumped from `0018f6c8` to `0018ef34`?(I mean a big pitch), Do those ESP address belong to same thread's stack??? Did the kernel play some tricks on ESP in ring3??? If so, WHY did it choose the address of `0018ef34` as handler callback's frame? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes same thread's stack. kernel copy the `CONTEXT` and `EXCEPTION_RECORD` to the user thread stack. off course bellow Esp of exception - for this already Esp serious decremented. and then `KiUserExceptionDispatcher` callback is called from kernel with pointer to this copied `CONTEXT` and `EXCEPTION_RECORD` records. finally your  `_except_handler` called. but if you look for `ContextRecord->Esp` you can note that it will be exactly same as `Esp` in `main()`. for real handlers implementation look `\VC\crt\src\i386\chandler4.c` and `\VC\crt\src\amd64\chandler.c`

Comment: Yeah, I know that CONTEXT must be a snapshot of hardware when exception occurs. so, `ContextRecord->Esp==Esp in main()`.In fact, we ought to blame on debugger's default setting which loses stack  trace. Btw,I know the modifiability of `*ContextRecord`, that's the mean by which kernel recover context of hardware as you wish before back to ring3. but WHY is the 2nd param `ExceptionRecord` of type`*` rather than `const *`?

Comment: ExceptionRecord really not const. the `ExceptionFlags` is modified during exception handling. we walk by stack two time ! first we looking for `__try/__except` blocks, until some not return `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER` then `_except_handlerX` called `RtlUnwindEx` which set `EXCEPTION_UNWIND` flag in `ExceptionFlags`  and again walk stack for `__try/__finally` handlers. look for `IS_DISPATCHING(Flag)` and `IS_UNWINDING(Flag)` macro in `winnt.h` and `wdm.h` - also study `chandler.c` note `if (IS_DISPATCHING(ExceptionRecord->ExceptionFlags))` switch

Comment: also `IS_TARGET_UNWIND` used in x64. simply `_except_handler` from `myseh.cpp` is very primitive. real handlers which support `__try/__except` and `__try/__finally` subcalls is for complex and need modify (`RtlUnwindEx`) `ExceptionFlags` how minimum. also nested `ExceptionRecord` too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the default debugger settings, not good enough to see all the details.  They were chosen to help you focus on your own code and get the debug session started as quickly as possible.

The [External Code] block tells you that there are parts of the stack frame that do not belong to code that you have written.  They don't, they belong to the operating system.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General and untick the "Enable Just My Code" option.

The [Frames below might be incorrect...] warning tells you that the debugger doesn't have accurate PDBs to correctly walk the stack.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols and tick the "Microsoft Symbol Servers" option and choose a cache location.  The debugger will now download the PDBs you need to debug through the operating system DLLs.  Might take a while, it is only done once.

You can reason out the big ESP change, the CONTEXT structure is quite large and takes up space on the stack.

After these changes you ought to now see something resembling:

```
ConsoleApplication1942.exe!_except_handler(_EXCEPTION_RECORD * ExceptionRecord, void * EstablisherFrame, _CONTEXT * ContextRecord, void * DispatcherContext) Line 22    C++
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler2@20()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler@20()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()    Unknown
ConsoleApplication1942.exe!main() Line 46   C++
ConsoleApplication1942.exe!invoke_main() Line 64    C++
ConsoleApplication1942.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 255    C++
ConsoleApplication1942.exe!__scrt_common_main() Line 300    C++
ConsoleApplication1942.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 17 C++
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

Recorded on Win10 version 1607 and VS2015 Update 2.  This isn't the correct way to write SEH handlers, find a better example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049836/17034).

Comment: Thanks.Yes, I know that the example is just aimed to tell its most fundamental concepts, not practical.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why this is not a correct reason to write SEH handlers? The reason why I ask is because I want to implement a little piece of code that will just put new handler at the beginning of SEH linked list, cause exception and then remove the handler from the list. Something along these lines:
void foo()
{
_EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD newHandlerStruct;
newHandlerStruct.Handler = (PEXCEPTION_ROUTINE) theHandlerFunc;
newHandlerStruct.Next = (_EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD*)__readfsdword(0x0);
__writefsdword(0x0, (DWORD64)&newHandlerStruct);
__debugbreak();
}

Comment: Pietrek's code is ancient, dates from the days before a 64-bit OS was common and the Internet relentlessly attacked Windows programs.  Highly exploitable, a basic way to turn data into executable code.  Microsoft had to come up with countermeasures, SafeSEH is the most basic one.  it is your compiler's job to generate the appropriate code.