# Is it possible to make all or most C++ errors manageable in VS?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, visual-studio-2013

In testing and debugging C++ code, there are often errors that visual studio can detect.  Usually it responds by creating a breaking window pop up that let's you halt execution and inspect the call stack and values of variables etc.

I am wondering if there is any possible way to have the debugger throw an exception instead of doing it's normal break.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
try {
    functionThatMightBreak(); // break as in, derefence null, uninitialized variable, iterator not derefenceable etc
} catch (SomeType e) {
    // a bit more stuff
}
```

Comment: Debugger does not throw exceptions... you probably mean something else. Check "debug->exceptions" and "tools->options->debug" - you may find a way to configure debugger's behavior to your liking.

Comment: Can you explain what behavior you're looking for from the debugger?  i don't think you want the debugger to "throw an exception" because that would cause VS to stop.

Comment: For example, if I accidentally dereference a null pointer I don't want a window to pop up asking if I want to break.  It would be nicer if it threw a NullPointerException as in Java (for example).  This is desirable because I want to run several tests and even if one fails I still want to be able to run the next because they're all independent and making them separate projects is unfeasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Structured Exceptional Handling aka SEH which is offered as a VC++-specific extension to the C++ language.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swezty51.aspx

cf.

- [Difference between a C++ exception and Structured Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786647/difference-between-a-c-exception-and-structured-exception)

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your code with the [`/EHa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx) compiler option, then the compiler will generate code such that Win32 exceptions (such as access violations) will be thrown like regular C++ exceptions and can be caught by `catch(...)` blocks.

If you do this, be careful that all of your code is compiled with the same options (and be especially careful of any third-party libraries you're using).

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions your are trying to catch (such as access violations) are os-specific. Visual Studio lets you catch them with `catch(...)` as an extension. You could also have a look at [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).